# Does the spell Wall of Fire shed light?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, vision-and-light

This may be a bit of a stupid question, but I wanted some RAW clarity on this spell regarding whether or not the fire creates light or not.

Within the body of the spell's description, nowhere does it state that the wall of fire creates any sort of light. This may seem counterintuitive, but I know that plenty of spells involving flame that specifically designate that they shed some form of 'bright' or 'dim' light. A few examples:

***Fire Shield***

> Thin and wispy flames wreathe your body for the duration, shedding bright light in a 10-foot radius and dim light for an additional 10 feet. You can end the spell early by using an action to dismiss it.

***Flame Blade***

> The flaming blade sheds bright light in a 10-foot radius and dim light for an additional 10 feet.

***Flaming Sphere***

> The sphere ignites flammable objects not being worn or carried, and it sheds bright light in a 20-foot radius and dim light for an additional 20 feet.

***Continual Flame***

> A flame, equivalent in brightness to a torch, springs forth from an object that you touch.

You get the picture. I know that spells like *Fireball* or *Flame Strike* have no light descriptions either, but I find *Wall of Fire* more suspect because this spell has a 1-minute duration.

Does *Wall of Fire* shed light?